# Calling function not working for me in a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a button using tkinter, which when pressed, it should delete all buttons on the screen, then it should make them reappear when I call the function for the original buttons. This is my intention but I cannot get it to work.

```
class login_screen:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        def menu_buttons():
            self.login_button = Button(master,
                              text="Login",
                              command=self.login,
                              relief=RIDGE,
                              height=2,
                              width=7,
                              bg="#ffb380")

            self.register_button = Button(master,
                              text="Register",
                              command=self.register,
                              relief=RIDGE,
                              height=2,
                              width=7,
                              bg="#ffb380")

            self.login_button.place(x=95, y=90)
            self.register_button.place(x=95, y=155)

        menu_buttons()


    def clear(self):
        self.login_button.destroy()
        self.register_button.destroy()

    def login(self):
        self.clear()
        menu_buttons()
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'menu_buttons' is not defined
```

When I press the login_button, it should clear everything then make the same buttons appear again. At the moment it only clears but does not reappear.

Comment: @JacobIRR nope, `menu_buttons` is defined in `__init__` and is not bound to `self`

Comment: @JacobIRR I tried that but i get "AttributeError: 'login_screen' object has no attribute 'menu_buttons' "

Comment: `menu_buttons()` is a function _local_ to the `__init__()` method. Make it a class method (with a `self` parameter) can reference it as `self.menu_buttons()` in the `login()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to re-use `menu_buttons`, don't define it in `__init__`, because the function will disappear as soon as `__init__` finishes, and so you won't be able to call it again:

```py
class login_screen:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.menu_buttons()


    # define the function here, so it can re-run
    def menu_buttons(self):
        self.login_button = Button(self.master,
                          text="Login",
                          command=self.login,
                          relief=RIDGE,
                          height=2,
                          width=7,
                          bg="#ffb380")

        self.register_button = Button(self.master,
                          text="Register",
                          command=self.register,
                          relief=RIDGE,
                          height=2,
                          width=7,
                          bg="#ffb380")

        self.login_button.place(x=95, y=90)
        self.register_button.place(x=95, y=155)


    def clear(self):
        self.login_button.destroy()
        self.register_button.destroy()

    def login(self):
        self.clear()
        # call self.menu_buttons to re-initialize
        self.menu_buttons()
```

Comment: You probably still need to call `self.menus_buttons` from `__init__` as well.

Comment: @chepner that's what I get for not reading code thoroughly, thanks for the catch

Comment: @C.Nivs The buttons do not show up now. When i try added "menu_buttons(self)" to call the buttons for the first time. It gives me NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You don't pass `self` to the function when calling it, that's handled for you

Answer (score 1):

you should take of init the menu_buttons method
and then pass self argument to menu_buttons

```
def menu_buttons(self):
```

At the moment menu_buttons is accesible only by your init method and other methods can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to completely destroy the buttons, so there is no need to attempt to recreate them in init since they still exists but are not visible.

```py
class login_screen:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.login_button = Button(master,
                                   text="Login",
                                   command=self.login,
                                   relief=RIDGE,
                                   height=2,
                                   width=7,
                                   bg="#ffb380")

        self.register_button = Button(master,
                                      text="Register",
                                      command=self.register,
                                      relief=RIDGE,
                                      height=2,
                                      width=7,
                                      bg="#ffb380")

    def place_buttons()
        self.login_button.place(x=95, y=90)
        self.register_button.place(x=95, y=155)

    def clear(self):
        self.login_button.place_forget()
        self.register_button.place_forget()

    def login(self):
        self.clear()
        self.place_buttons()
```